# How do you measure query performance in Cassandra?

Tags: performance, cassandra, measurement

I am still new in learning Cassandra, and I am doing some measurements, regarding memory and processor resources for each of my query. Does Cassandra has her own way to show performance of query or should I use some third party tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tracing switched on to see the internal steps.

```
TRACING ON
```

For the query below

```
INSERT INTO cycling.cyclist_name (
   id, 
   lastname, 
   firstname
  ) 
  VALUES (
   e7ae5cf3-d358-4d99-b900-85902fda9bb0, 
   'FRAME',
   'Alex'
  );
```

The below is the trace log

```
Tracing session: 9b378c70-b114-11e6-89b5-b7fad52e1885

 activity                                                                                                                                                        | timestamp                  | source    | source_elapsed | client
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------
                                                                                                                                              Execute CQL3 query | 2016-11-22 16:34:34.300000 | 127.0.0.1 |              0 | 127.0.0.1
 Parsing INSERT INTO cycling.cyclist_name (id, lastname, firstname) VALUES (e7ae5cf3-d358-4d99-b900-85902fda9bb0, 'FRAME','Alex'); [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2016-11-22 16:34:34.305000 | 127.0.0.1 |           5935 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                               Preparing statement [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2016-11-22 16:34:34.308000 | 127.0.0.1 |           9199 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                 Determining replicas for mutation [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2016-11-22 16:34:34.330000 | 127.0.0.1 |          30530 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                                        Appending to commitlog [MutationStage-3] | 2016-11-22 16:34:34.330000 | 127.0.0.1 |          30979 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                               Adding to cyclist_name memtable [MutationStage-3] | 2016-11-22 16:34:34.330000 | 127.0.0.1 |          31510 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                                                                Request complete | 2016-11-22 16:34:34.333633 | 127.0.0.1 |          33633 | 127.0.0.1
```

Reference link: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshTracing.html

Comment: thank you for quick reply, but it seems that with TRACING ON I can see just query execution time and I need more info about query performances

Comment: What are the info, you expecting as part of query performances?

Comment: I would like to know how much memory was needed for query execution and info about CPU consumption

Comment: There is a table `node_slow_log` which logs the latency of each query based on the slow query threshold. Other than that, I don't think the CPU utilisation is available per query